# Estimate sample size for cumulative distribution function

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I'm measuring two conversion rates. I'm interested if the difference between them is at least some percentage unit in one direction.

I'm assuming both sample proportions are normally distributed over their means, and that their delta is normally distributed over `p1 - p2`. I can then use the cumulative distribution function to get the probability of the delta being at least some value.

My question is if there's any way to estimate the required sample size for this kind of test?